# No accurate type for elements in nested arrays

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given this code:

```
[['one',1], ['two',2], ['three',3], ['four',4]]
  .forEach(([text, num]) => text + num);
```

the most correct type I'm getting from TS is `string | number`. Can we do it better? What does TS can not infer the types more accurately?

Comment: which particular thing is `string | num` - `text`? The arrays? The result?

Comment: sorry for not being precise. When I hover over `text` or `num` I'm getting `string | number`

Comment: @leszczu450 you want a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple). Or in this case an array of them. When typescript sees a heterogenous array, it can't assume that the types at the indicies are consistent.

Comment: yeah, but why does TS can not infer it by its own?

Comment: Hmm, or one more thing. Why do I need an array of tuples to type it? I'm destructuring the array in the callback signature, right?

Comment: `([['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4]] as const).forEach(([text, num]) => text + num)`

Comment: "why does TS can not infer it by its own?" Because sometimes people want to use arrays for different things, like modifying them, and `[0,1,"two"][2]=2` would fail if `[0, 1, "two"]` were inferred as a tuple of `[number, number, string]` instead of `Array<string | number>`.  Even `[0, 1, 2][2]=3` would fail if inferred as `[0, 1, 2]` instead of `[number, number, number]`.  The default behavior of the compiler is a tradeoff that works in some situations.  If it doesn't work for yours, you can use a `const` assertion like @ford04 mentions.

Comment: @ford04 can I type it in some other way? Or is it only `as const`

Comment: @leszczu450 did you look at the link I provided? Here's [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nKBeKBtAzsATgSwHYDmANFHgK4C2ARhFgLoDcAUEwBSqoDkceEnJARjokuwAO5x+UAEzC0nYAAssEPiQDMcrvDJYpAFjp0oAQ3SwEqOgEoAdPCwBREwGNFrdsAgAPYCXIUNsgAfFBevlAA1KSU1kA).

Comment: @JaredSmith yes, but how does it relate to this topic? I know, what tuples are. I just dont know why I can not do typing something like [string, number].

Comment: @leszczu450 *that is a tuple*. It's a 2 element vector with specified types at each index. See the link I just added to the TS playground, or the identical answer below.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript out box takes very loose assumption about the type. To define clearly that this array has this shape not by example, but always, we can or specify the type explicitly, or do the shortcut by using [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

```
([['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4]] as const)
.forEach(([text, num]) => text + num);
```

Now TS is inferencing very strict, that every element is a tuple, and even specify it to the union of possible values.

Eventually you can assert to less specified type like array of tuples `[string, number][]`.

```
([['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4]] as [string, number][])
.forEach(([text, num]) => text + num);
```

The most explicit way would be to just typed that. I would prefer that:

```
type StrNumber = [string, number];
const arr: StrNumber[] = [['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4]];
arr.forEach(([text, num]) => text + num);
```

---

**Edit**
One thing to add, as there was additional question in the comment. Why such does not work:

```
[['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4]]
    .forEach(([text, num]: [string, number]) => text + num) // error
```

It does not because TS is checking types from top to bottom. It means that type declaration below has to match type declaration above. If you are saying that your predicate has an argument of `[string, number]` it means that it can work only on such, but unfortunetly TS sees the above array elements and inference them as `string | number)[]`. It is clear that function which works on [string, number] cannot work on wider type `string | number)[]`. You cannot derive above type from bottom, you can derive from top to bottom.

Comment: how can we do it using tuples?

Comment: you can or explicitly say this is `[string, number][]` or assert that, take a look on my edited answer.

Comment: Why can't I do it like this:
`[['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4]].forEach(([text, num]: [string,number]) => text + num);`

Comment: @leszczu450 I have added some information about your comment question. Hope it helps